# Why does opening the NERDTree in VIM need about 1~2 seconds?

Tags: vim

I installed the NERDTree plugin in the vimrc

```
" Define map <Leader>
let mapleader = " "
let maplocalleader = " "

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
call plug#end()

nmap <Leader>nt :NERDTreeToggle<cr>
```

when I input <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, it needs about 2.x seconds to open the NERDTree no matter how many files/dirs in the current directory.
I don't know why. anything I can do to improve the performance to open it e.g.(in 1 second)

thx.

Comment: Do you have another keybinding that starts with `<Leader>nt` by chance? In that case, see the `timeout` option(s) for details. https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27timeout%27

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can answer this, barring finding a bug, is to profile Nerdtree using vim's built-in tools. Take a look at `:help profile` to see how to use them.